# Renombrar imagen al cargar en servidor PHP

Tags: php, imagen

Que tal, tengo una duda quizá muy básica pero no logro encontrar un código que funcione con el mio.

Lo que quiero hacer es guardar una imagen en mi servidor(ya lo hace) pero **que se guarde con un nombre único y evitar duplicados**

Aquí mi código:

```
/*OBTENEMOS LOGO*/
    $imgA = $_FILES['img-af']['tmp_name'];
    $idUsu = $_POST['idUsu'];
    $establecimiento = new establecimiento();
    $destinoB="";
    $maxWidth=300; //ANCHO
    $maxHeight=300; //ALTO

    if ($imgA!="") {
        $destinoB = "logos/".$_FILES['img-af']['name'];
        $tamano = getimagesize($imgA);
        if($tamano[0] <= $maxWidth){
            if($tamano[1] <= $maxHeight){
                move_uploaded_file($imgA, $destinoB);
                $resultado = $establecimiento->cambiarLogo($idUsu,$destinoB);
                    if($resultado){
                        echo "OK";
                    }else {
                        echo "FAIL";
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Todo funciona bien, sin embargo al subir una imagen con el mismo nombre la reemplaza. Quiero evitar eso.

Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Intenta generandole un nombre unico con la funcion [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) que genera un numero unico.

Solo debes de concatenar el valor de retorno con el nombre de la imagen y listo.

```
//..
if ($imgA!="") {
    $destinoB = "logos/". uniqid(rand(), true) .'_'.$_FILES['img-af']['name'];
    $tamano = getimagesize($imgA);
//..
```

Genera un nombre largo pero te servira para que no te reemplaces las imagenes con el mismo nombre.

Comment: Gracias Einer, me sirvió perfecto. Se podría también aplicar para modificar por completo el nombre de la imagen?

Comment: Claro dulce. Puedes utilizarlo para eso.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar un GUID para cada archivo que subas.

```
function guid($p_corchetes) {//Genera una GUID Identificador Unico
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
        return com_create_guid();
    } else {
        mt_srand((double) microtime() * 10000); //optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45); // "-"
        $uuid = "";
        if ($p_corchetes == true) {
            $uuid = chr(123); //
        }
        $uuid = $uuid . substr($charid, 0, 8) . $hyphen
                . substr($charid, 8, 4) . $hyphen
                . substr($charid, 12, 4) . $hyphen
                . substr($charid, 16, 4) . $hyphen
                . substr($charid, 20, 12);

        if ($p_corchetes == true) {
            $uuid = $uuid . chr(125); //
        }

        return $uuid;
    }
}
```

$nombre = guid(false);
   echo 'GUID:'.$nombre;